# Topology for using Ignite in embedded, full replication mode, with native persistence (Kubernetes)

Tags: ignite

One of my backend service uses Ignite. The backend service itself is stateless, meaning, the service doesn't have any internal or shared states, and can scale up and down on the need. The backend service is deployed in Kubernetes.

I have used the Ignite, now, in the embedded way, with cache mode set to `REPLICATED`, and native persistence enabled. Additionally I have also enabled the `baselineAutoAdjustEnabled`. The reason for using replicated mode is to have the data available to all the backend instances locally & consistent way.

The application seems to work correctly -

- as and when data is modifies the data gets replicated across all the instances of the backend
- data replication works even if a new instance joins the topology after (long time) the initial baseline is set & activated.

The question now is, is this is the right approach in running the Ignite in embedded (server mode), with full replication, and native persistence?

Answer (score 1):

In general your design looks well. But be careful with using of `baselineAutoAdjustEnabled`. This feature works only in case of topology changes do not leads to lost partitions. But in your case, as you use only replicated caches, any node stoping should not lead to lost partitions.

Embeded mode in this case does not have any matter.